# Position a div inside a smartphone image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a slideshow embedded inside a smartphone image for my website.
Creating the slideshow is pretty easy using [Owl Carousel](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2).
What i'm unable to do is placing my div inside the phone image so that it covers all the screen, even when the image has different sizes.

I started by measuring the margins that I had to apply in percents, but I don't like this solution.

Is there a way to manually set the four corners of the div relatively to the image ?

I can use jQuery

[image: iphone gold]

Comment: Please take a look at this site, hope it helps. http://www.eastros.com/frame-carousel/samples/index.html

Comment: I think the best solution is to wrap the img and slider within a outter-div and use absolute position for the slider and margins (left, right, top and bottom since it's absolutely positioned) with persentages will do the trick

Comment: I was trying to avoid the percentage approach as it didn't seem clean to me, but looks like it's the only way

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the **SNIPPET** below.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:0
});
```

```css
.screen .item{
  background-color:#5fba7d;
}

.phone{
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKQ2K.png);
    width: 320px !important;
    height: 650px;
    background-position: -25px 0;
}

.no-js .owl-carousel, .owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    position: relative;
    top: 48px;
    width: 278px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

.owl-stage-outer, .owl-item, .item{
  height:100%;
}

.owl-stage{
  height:calc(100% - 153px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.green.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="phone">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme screen">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
</div>
<div>
```